# Benefits of using a create() method instead of the class constructor?

Tags: c++

In [this code](https://github.com/TheCherno/Hazel/blob/master/Hazel/src/Hazel/Core/Window.h), `class Window` has a create() method. The Windows OS' window class is [here](https://github.com/TheCherno/Hazel/blob/master/Hazel/src/Platform/Windows/WindowsWindow.h). Why was it done this way instead of using a constructor, and thus saving the hassle of doing `auto win = Window::create()`?

I believe that it was done so they could return a `nullptr`. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Window::create` is a "factory function". The main reason why factory functions are sometimes used instead of constructors in C++ is that a constructor `T::T` can only create objects of type `T`, whereas a factory function `T::create` can return a pointer to `T`, which could potentially point to a derived class. The actual type created can depend on the arguments to the factory function.

Answer (score 0):

Brian is correct.  `Window.Create()` is an example of a [factory method](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method/cpp/example).

"Factories" can be useful in many circumstances. To elaborate:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)
>
> Factories can be used when:
>
> - The creation of an object makes reuse impossible without significant duplication of code.
> - The creation of an object requires access to information or resources that should not be contained within the composing class.
> - The lifetime management of the generated objects must be centralized to ensure a consistent behavior within the application.